# Covering spaces of $S^1\vee S^1$ up to isomorphism of covering spaces with basepoints.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Problem 1.3.10 in Hatcher asks to find all connected 2 and 3-sheeted covering spaces of $S^1\vee S^1$ up to isomorphism of covering spaces without basepoints.

I accept that the answer to this question is all 4-valent 2 and 3 vertex graphs with appropriately labeled (directed) edges.  My question is: how does this answer change if one asks for the covering spaces up to isomorphism *with* basepoints?